# How to get ngFor index from DI in nested component

Tags: angular

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <td><action del></acticon></td>
</tr>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'action[del]',
    template: `<a (click)="delete()">del</a>`
})
export class DeleteActionComponent {

    constructor(private items:any[],private item:any) { }

    delete(){
        const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
        this.items.splice(index, 1)
    }
}
```

I don't want use `@Input` items and item from view, this will cause I write lots of directive in html template. Does the `ngForOf` directive has those providers. Or has some thing to get those value indirectly.

Comment: what about emitting an event instead? This way this parent component can manage the state and the child does not need to know it's index. Also, if the component needs to know it's index (I presume to mutate some object) it makes it less reusable and harder to test.

Comment: I want create common action to ngFor, eg: add, delete, edit @Mudassir